# What is the simplest way to boost the output of a waveform generator to drive a piezo mesh?

Tags: boost, waveform, piezo, function-generator

I am trying to generate a ~40vpp sine waveform with a Rigol DG1022Z.  Its maximum is 20Vpp.

I want to test the device at frequency ranges of a piezo device from 40kHz to up to 200kHz. This is to drive a tiny piezo mesh (less than 1W required output drive) similar to [these.](https://www.steminc.com/PZT/en/metal-mesh-piezo-atomizer)

I understand I need an amplifier of some sort but is there a simpler way than getting one of [these machines?](https://www.accelinstruments.com/Products/TS250/Waveform-Amp.html)

Can I build a simple op-amp circuit? Would it require an 80V (+/- 40V) supply?

Comment: You can build your own amplifier, with op-amp or with something else, but you will need a +/- 40V power supply to make a +/- 40V waveform. I think there are also resonant circuits which can use a lower voltage supply, but I don't understand them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need an amplifier. A transformer is a simpler way to increase the voltage. The signal generator has a 50 ohm output impedance, and the piezo datasheet suggests it has a 250 ohm impedance. So a 2:1 step up transformer will double the voltage level while providing a reasonable impedance match as well (250 / 4 = 62.5 ohms load on the generator).